# Passing NS Core Data context ref between View Controllers

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my initial View Controller, I set up my NS Core Data document, and get the managedOBjectContext.  I then pass this to whichever view controller that comes next.  It works, but it seems ugly.  Any time I have a new segue or move to another area of the application, I need to pass this reference.

Wouldn't it be easier to create this reference in the appDelagate and instead have this globally available to all view controllers?

Answer (score 3):

Here's an article on a good method of making a data manager that exists outside your controller hierarchy and can be used where needed: http://nachbaur.com/blog/smarter-core-data

The write-up explains the theory and has links to an implementation.

Comment: The link referenced is dead.

Comment: Looks like the author has archived the page.  Try: http://nachbaur.com/2011/04/19/smarter-core-data/

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to pass the core data context. It's possible to retrieve it in the view controller by doing something like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication\ delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

However I actually prefer doing it by passing the context when initiating a controller.